# jQuery won't toggle css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I know there are tons of jquery css toggle threads, but I took my own approach, and I can't see why this doesn't work:

```
 <script>
    $("#id").click(function(){ 
        if($("#example").css("visibility"=="hidden"))
        {
            console.log("if reached");
            $("#example").css( "visibility", "visible" );
            console.log($("#example").css("visibility"));
        }
        else
        {
            $("#example").css( "visibility", "hidden" );
            console.log("else reached");
            console.log($("#example").css("visibility"));
        }
    })
    </script>
```

Tried it in both FF and Chrome, and it simply doesn't work!

Here's the HTML:

```
<input id="id" type="text"></input>
<div id="example">Test Test Test </div>
```

Comment: Your if statement is totally wrong.

Comment: Also the value returned by `.css('color')` is not dependable... it could be a hexa value or a rgb value etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the color returned by [.css('color')](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is not dependable, it way vary depending on browsers.

> Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the
>   value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example,
>   computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can
>   be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers
>   may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually
>   equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

I think the best approach will be is to use a class like

```js
var $example = $("#example");
$("#id").click(function() {
  $example.toggleClass('red');
  if ($example.hasClass('red')) {
    console.log('has red now');
  } else {
    console.log('default color');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id" type="button"></input>
<div id="example">Test Test Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Html code:

```
<input id="id" type="button"></input>
<div id="example">Test Test Test </div>
```

Js code :

```
$(function(){   
    $("#id").click(function(){         
        if( $('#example').is(':visible') ) {
            $('#example').hide();
        } else {
            $('#example').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code is already there, just a syntax error, `.css("visibility"=="hidden")` evaluates to `css(true)`. You want to check the return, eg `.css("visibility")=="hidden"`

```
 <script>
$("#id").click(function(){ 
    if($("#example").css("visibility")=="hidden"))
    {
        console.log("if reached");
        $("#example").css( "visibility", "visible" );
        console.log($("#example").css("visibility"));
    }
    else
    {
        $("#example").css( "visibility", "hidden" );
        console.log("else reached");
        console.log($("#example").css("visibility"));
    }
})
</script>
```